# angularjs bindToController value is undefined in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using `controllerAs` on my directive and used `bindToController`.
But bindToController parameter is undefined on controller. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/28gsvr62/172/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope){

    $scope.change = function(){
        $scope.fullname = 'Brian Kim';
    }
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      name: '='
    },     
    controller: function () {
        console.log(this.name); // undefined
    },
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    bindToController: true,
    template: '{{ctrl.name}}',
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your demo works as expected. Parent controller `$scope.fullname` is undefined during initialization. It receives value only after `change` button is hit. See updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/10fmrb8n/

Answer (score 0):

Hi the problem is that you do a console.log(this.name) on the init of the directive controller .. but   $scope.fullname  is filled with value only when you click the button and call the  $scope.change  function .. if you want it is not undefined you've to do something like:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope){
    $scope.fullname = 'Brian Kim'; //<-- HERE YOU INITIALIZE IT

    $scope.change = function(){
        $scope.fullname = 'Brian Kim';
    }
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      name: '='
    },     
    controller: function () {
        console.log(this.name);
    },
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    bindToController: true,
    template: '{{ctrl.name}}',
  };
});
```

So initialize it

Comment: how can access a parameter at initialization time? I need it